# How to join local AD domain during Windows 10 install?

Tags: windows, windows-10, active-directory, windows-domain

During Windows 10 install, I'd like to join my company's Active Directory domain instead of adding a new local user. Or maybe just login with the (hidden?) local Administrator-account.

During the install, I am asked if this is a personal or organizational computer. I choose organizational, as it is my company's computer. It then wants to sign in with a Microsoft account, but we use "normal" local AD on our own Windows Server. I can then click "Domain join instead", but this leads to a user creation process. Why is this, when I want to join a domain, where presumably my user should be located?

Is there any way to not create a local user during the install?

[image: Set up for organization]
[image: Microsoft logon - nope, please]
[image: User creation process]

Comment: Are you an Administrator of the domain?  Adding a machine to the Active Directory domain isn't something a normal user normally does.

Comment: @Ramhound: [By default,](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/dubaisec/2016/02/01/who-can-add-workstation-to-the-domain/) AD allows a regular User to join up to 10 machines. It's quite possible that a company might have self-service setup. And vice versa, if an Administrator is setting up a new workstation, why wouldn't they want to do the join as soon as possible from the setup screen (just like it used to be possible in Win2000/XP era)?

Comment: @grawity - Even if there is a self-service setup, the user should be asking help from an Administrator on the domain, the Administrator will be able to help them.

Comment: I have a domain admin login :-)

Comment: Use Microsoft Deployment Toolkit (MDT) and Task Sequences.  I haven't done it for a few years, so I won't make a full Answer here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can automate the whole process using unattend.xml which is can be placed in the c:\windows\system32\sysprep folder.

This is only part of the file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<unattend xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:unattend">
    <servicing></servicing>
    <settings pass="specialize">
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-UnattendedJoin" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <Identification>
                <JoinDomain>ad</JoinDomain>
                <JoinWorkgroup></JoinWorkgroup>
                <Credentials>
                    <Domain>domain_goes_here</Domain>
                    <Password>password_goes_here</Password>
                    <Username>username_goes_here</Username>
                </Credentials>
                <MachineObjectOU>OU=here,OU=there,OU=everywhere,DC=etc,DC=domain,DC=etc</MachineObjectOU>
            </Identification>
        </component>
```

There is no need to even see this screen if you complete the whole unattend.xml file.

Microsoft even provides a tool part of the MDT deployment toolkit to generate this file.

[image]

Step

1. download and install MDT
2. Copy windows DVD onto hard drive
3. Launch Windows System Image manager
4. Bottom left select the install.wim in folder in step 2

[image]

5. Yes
6. Wait........

When done the Answer file area looks like this

[image]

[image: fully load]

When done save your answer file.

Make a bootable USB drive and place it in the root folder of the USB drive.

Addition info:

https://win10.guru/windows-10-unattended-install-media-part-3-answer-file-for-oobe/